# Linking records in Communication Templates

Tags: maximo

Following the instructions in this [IBM article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLW8/com.ibm.mbs.doc/commtmplt/t_linking_records_communtemp.html), I have included a link to a record in an comm template. My link looks like this `http://:HOSTNAME/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?event=loadapp&value=:APP&uniqueid=:OWNERID`.

This link from the IBM article only gets to the default, i.e "List" tab for most applications. Can I somehow add a specific tab (standard or custom) of named application when implementing this as a link in Comm Template?

Comment: This may help: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/power-maximo-url-parameters

Comment: Actually, by using the uniqueid parameter in the URL it will take you to the "main" tab (whatever that may be), not the "List" tab. The link in the comment above gives more information, but the link at the bottom of _that_ article takes you to a page that gives a lot more information, though it may be out of date. In Bruno's page, he does call out a tabid and changetab parameter. I believe I did use those once 10 or so years ago, but I'm not sure if they still work (or exactly how I got them to work back then).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on [this blog post](https://bportaluri.com/2012/04/maximo-urls.html) by Bruno Portaluri, and comments from others on that post, it looks like you should be able to add `changetab=yourtabid` to the URL.

Based on your question, the whole URL would then be `http://:HOSTNAME/maximo/ui/maximo.jsp?event=loadapp&value=:APP&uniqueid=:OWNERID&changetab=plans` if the app your link was to had a tab with ID `plans`, or XML `<tab id="plans" ...`, in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both, Dex, and Maximo.Wiki for your contributions>
Your comments actually led me to figure out all that I needed to solve my issue
Oh, woe how many times I was actually phrasing my problem incorrectly because corporate english is not primary variant of it and hence having to end up digging SO for answers

Thanks again!

Comment: One might think that someone knowledgeable in Maximo as you, sir, would have more patience for novice questions about it. Nevermind the SO etiquette about questions etc

Comment: I have answered many novice questions with lots of patience. I do apologize if I have come off as abrupt. However, part of making StackOverflow be a useful site is making sure that questions and answers have some level of quality. I will edit your question to be as good as I can, and admittedly I'm not the best, but it would be good for you to include some content from the page you link to. But this answer has zero content. It's not an answer. It's a thanksgiving. Giving thanks is important, but it is not an answer. Please take this as encouragement and free training.